# How to encode function signature besides parameters using eth_abi

Tags: blockchain, python, abi, encoding

I want to encode a contract's function signature together with parameters and values using python, more explicitely the eth_abi library.

```
tokenA = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c"
tokenB = "0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56"

abiEncoded = eth_abi.encode_abi(['address', 'address'], [tokenA, tokenB]).hex()
```

The code above  work perfectly fine for the parameters, and returns an expected result, however  I am not sure how to  add the  leading 4bytes  (big-endian encoding) signature inside the hash .

**Expected result**
`0xe6a43905000000000000000000000000bb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c000000000000000000000000e9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56`

**My result**
`000000000000000000000000bb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c000000000000000000000000e9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your library doesn't seem to provide a direct equivalent to abi.encodeWithSignature neither of keccak256, the later one is mandatory in order to get the function identifier.

Those 4 bytes that you are looking for are part of what I just talked about : the function identifier. Basically, those are the first 4 bytes of the keccak256 of the function signature.

`0xe6a43905` are the first 4 bytes of the keccak256 of : `getPair(address,address)`

A very minimalist solution using the pysha3 module :

```
import sha3
k = sha3.keccak_256()
k.update(b'getPair(address,address)')
print (k.hexdigest()[:8])
# OUTPUTS : e6a43905
```

But you might be better off using [Web3py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#) which is up to date, and contains every helper functions that you might need for such a task.